# Lista con 10 primeros números primos

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Estoy intentando crear un programa con Prolog que inserte en una lista los 10 primeros números primos, pero no consigo resolverlo.

Mi aproximación al problema es:

1. Comprobar si un número es primo.

```
       primeNumber(A) :-
            A > 1,                 % Negative numbers, 0 and 1 are not prime.
            prime_prime(A, 2).     % Begin iteration:

        prime_prime(A, B) :-       % Test if A divides by B without remainder
            B >= A                % The limit was reached?
            ->  true               %     Then it's prime.
            ;   0 is A mod B       % B divides A without a remainder?
            ->  false              %     Then it's not prime.
            ;   succ(B, C),        % Otherwise: C is B + 1
                prime_prime(A, C). % Test if C divides A.
```

2. Código para añadir un número a una lista:

```
        list_member(X,[X|_]).
        list_member(X,[_|TAIL]) :- list_member(X,TAIL).

        list_append(A,T,T) :- list_member(A,T),!.
        list_append(A,T,[A|T]).
```

La verdad es que no sabría cómo unir esos dos códigos ni cómo ir añadiendo otro número a la lista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues parece ser que, como en tantas otras cosas en la vida, cuando se hablan de los problemas, o poner voz a los problemas de uno, ayuda a encontrar las soluciones. Y eso me ha pasado.

Mi aproximacion no iba muy desencamida, pero no entendia muy bien como enlazar las dos reglas. Finalmente, he entendido mejor como funciona prolog y he dado con la solucion.

```
primeNumber(A) :-
    A > 1,                      % Negative numbers, 0 and 1 are not prime.
    prime_prime(A, 2).          % Begin iteration:

prime_prime(A, B) :-            % Test if A divides by B without remainder
    B >= A                      % The limit was reached?
      ->  true                  %     Then it's prime.
    ;   0 is A mod B            % B divides A without a remainder?
    ->  false                   %     Then it's not prime.
    ;   succ(B, C),             % Otherwise: C is B + 1
        prime_prime(A, C).      % Test if C divides A.


primeList(A,B,[]) :- A > B, !.  % Check if the lower limit is bigger than the upper limit
primeList(A,B,[A|L]) :-         % Add the lower limit to the list
    primeNumber(A), !,          %   if is prime
    A1 is A+1,                  % The lower limit is one space closer.
    primeList(A1,B,L).          % Back to test a new number.
primeList(A,B,L) :-             % If it is not prime.
    A1 is A+1,                  %   The lower limit is one up
    B1 is B+1,                  %   and the upper limit too, so it keeps the distance between them
    primeList(A1,B1,L).         % Back to thes a new number.
```

Espero que esto ayude a alguien mas en el futuro.

Gracias.

PD: Para quien ha editado mi mensaje anterior. No es que no sepa escribir, es que tengo un teclado ingles y no se muy bien como poner los acentos o la enye. Gracias igualmente.

Comment: Buen hallazgo! En unas horas puedes incluso marcar tu respuesta como aceptada para que otros sepan que tiene una solución aceptada